# URLSEssion Does not send any response

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

I was trying to learn the basics of networking with openweather api.

Implemented a very basic struct like this.

```
protocol WeatherManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateWeather(_ weatherManager : WeatherManager, weather : WeatherModel)
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}
struct WeatherManager {
    
    var delegate : WeatherManagerDelegate?
    var temp : Double = 0.0
    let weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=40ca58efce193db0fc801564afb08283&units=metric"
    func fetchWheather(cityName : String){
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
     performRequest(with: urlString)
    }
    func performRequest(with urlString: String){
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safedata = data {
                    if let weather = self.parseJSON(weatherData: safedata){
                        //                        let WeatherVC = WeatherViewController()
                        self.delegate!.didUpdateWeather(self, weather: weather)
                    }
                    print("Data is \(safedata)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    func parseJSON(weatherData:Data)-> WeatherModel?{
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData =   try  decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            let id = decodedData.weather[0].id
            let temp = decodedData.main.temp
            let name = decodedData.name
            let weather =  WeatherModel(conditionID: id, cityName: name, temperature: temp)
            return weather
        } catch{
            print("error is \(error)")
            delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    
}
```

But the issue is none of the print statements inside the requests are giving any outputs , nor i am able to update the UI. But the URL is giving the correct JSON Response when tried in browser

I am using the latest XCode on iOS 15 (iPhone 11 Device) with M1 Pro chip mac.

Found some threads which mentions to use "open with rosetta" but none of which worked.
also, not getting any errors on the console
Any solution?

Edit : Called in VC like this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    
    if let city = searchTextField.text {
        weatherManager.fetchWeather(cityName: city)
    }
    
    searchTextField.text = ""
    
}
```

Comment: How do you call the methods? Be aware that the code doesn't work if the city name contains a space character like New York. You have to (percent) encode the URL

Comment: Updated : Also it willnot work with Cities like "London". Even when i tried with the completed project from gitHub it was showing the same issue.

Comment: "let url = URL(string: urlString)" Do you pass that test at all? I hope the appid you gave is not private. You should use URLQueryItem to construct your URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
```

…instead of creating local session variable within the function scope

And if `error != nil` then don't return from that block. Simply use `if-else` for error handling.